# InvalidCastException from Entity.DynamicProxies.MyEntityClass to Entity.DbSet`1[MyEntityClass]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having difficulty understanding why I am getting an InvalidCastException
Here is the error message that I'm getting:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Man_58184D79075BC811252680D7866D3D69D0C46FD038D3B123A5E3B102E1FC77A2' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[ConsoleApplication1.Man]'.

- **Man** is the name of the entity class being passed to TEntity
- I've marked the location of the error with a comment in the code.

The purpose of this repository class is to hold a given DbContext and DbSet, and call its methods to delete records and/or display all records of the given DbSet.

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private DbContext dbContext;
    private DbSet<TEntity> dbSet { get; set; }
    public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
       this.dbContext = dbContext;
       this.dbSet = this.dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
         TEntity entity = dbSet.Find(id);
         dbSet.Remove(entity);
         dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void DisplayAll()
    {
        IQueryable Query = from item in dbContext.Set<TEntity>()  
                           where true
                           select item;

        foreach (DbSet<TEntity> x in Query) //InvalidCastException
        {
            // print entity fields to console here.
        }

    }
}
```

These are the lines in my main program that I use to create a Repository Object:

**TestDataBaseEntities** is the type of DbContext object I use to refer to my entity model.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int myID;
        var dbEntities = new TestDatabaseEntities();
        Repository<Man> ManTracker = new Repository<Man>(dbEntities);

        ManTracker.Display();  // exception thown in this method.
        Console.WriteLine("Choose ID to delete from Men list");
        myID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        ManTracker.Delete(myID);
        ManTracker.Display();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is something missing here - what's dbContext.Set()? From what I can see DbContext has two overloads Set<Type>() which is returning strongly typed DbSet<Type> and Set(Type) which returns just DbSet(). Anyways I assume you use dbContext.Set(typeof(Man)) to get the DbSet but EF created proxy types for your entities (i.e. automatically derived from your entity to add some functionality like lazy loading) and therefore it cannot now be down cast to Man. You can tell that it is a proxy because it starts with the name of the base type and then has the hash DynamicProxies.Man_5818...

Comment: My apologies. I marked the wrong line as the source of the problem.  I edited it and now it is correctly marked.  

foreach (DbSet x in Query) //InvalidCastException

Comment: How about answering the questions above?

Comment: dbContext.Set() is the DbSet of the DbContext object that I want to use in the Delete() and DisplayAll() methods.  I edited my main post to show the calling lines in my main program on a code block beneath the one I originally posted.  I didn't use dbContext.Set(typeof(Man)) to get the DbSet.

Comment: Sorry, I can see it now - when you edit the post you can see that this is actually this.dbContext.Set<TEntity>(); and not this.dbContext.Set(); - I think it is because of <pre> will try to fix this.

Comment: Your code should work if you disable proxy creation by setting `DbContextConfiguration.ProxyCreationEnabled` to false. However this means that some things (e.g. lazy loading) will not work.

Comment: I am trying to learn this stuff.  So these dynamic proxies are created at run-time?  and that's why they can't be typecasted to a DbSet, which is defined at compile time?  I never realized I was creating dynamic proxies even.  Is it good programming style to disable lazy loading?

Comment: EF generates proxies dynamically at runtime (if it is possible to derive from your class and overwrite properties). You can find a short article on proxies here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592886. Disabling/not disabling lazy loading is not about style but it's about whether you depend on this functionality or not. If you disable lazy loading you will have to make sure that all navigation properties are loaded before you use them (e.g. using .Include). On the other hand it may mean that you will send less queries to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I kind of got it to work, but not by disabling lazy loading.  see the line that says 'foreach (DbSet<TEntity> x in Query) //InvalidCastException'?
I changed that to 'foreach (TEntity x in Query) //InvalidCastException' and it worked, except I need to print to console each of the values in the columns of each TEntity Object, and if I don't know what class object it is, I don't know how I can print the column values out.  I will look into this and see if I can find a useful function that does this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the answer.  I was using the wrong type in the for each statement.

Instead of doing DbSet I should have used TEntity instead.

But this is misleading because even though i'm able to typecast to TEntity, I would need to have code that prints the fields of the TEntity object, and TEntity doesn't have access to the fields I need to print.  Instead of using a separate repository class, I think i should use an interface that defines a function called display, and gets implemented by each entity class somehow without modifying the auto-generated code from creating the model from the database.  Perhaps by creating classes that inherit from the entity classes, and then implement the interface.  I had the thought to do it this way because to keep things object-oriented, it seemed to make sense to me that an object shouldn't rely on another object to display its contents to the user, it should display them itself.